# The name of the application on the button

Tags: python, json, tkinter

Is it possible to make the file name appear instead of the path, and I didn't damage the json path?
For example: C:users/desktop/book.txt.
I would like to make it so that only the name is displayed, for example, book,txt. The name, and that is, the file_name variable is displayed on the button.

The code is fully working.

my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as tfd
import json
import os

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Open")
window.geometry("600x400")
window.resizable(False, False)

file_name = ""


def load_json():
    global file_name


    if os.path.exists("Filen.json"):
        with open("Filen.json") as file1:
            contents = json.load(file1)


            if len(contents) > 0:
                if contents[0] != "":
                    file_name = contents[0]



    else:
        with open("Filen.json", "w") as file1:
            json.dump([file_name], file1, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

def openu():
    global file_name


    load_json()
    if file_name == "":

        path = tfd.askopenfilename()

        if path != ():
            file_name = path

            btn1.config(text=file_name)
    else:
        os.startfile(file_name)

        with open("Filen.json", "w") as file1:
            json.dump([file_name], file1, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)


load_json()
btn1 =  tk.Button(window, text=file_name, command=openu)
btn1.place(x = 20, y = 25)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the file name easily if you have path like below.

```
import os
file_name = os.path.basename(your_path)
```

If  you have a path C:users/desktop/book.txt then you will get file name as shown below.

```
file_name=os.path.basename('C:users/desktop/book.txt')
```

Comment: os.startfile(file_name)
The specified file cannot be found. 
Before that, I specified: file_name = os.path.basename(path)

Comment: Then you have to check whether the file exists.

Comment: I click on the button, only the file name remains, BUT however it can't find the path

Comment: If you are using this method then you already have the path. Why you again find the path?

Comment: @FiolDoll: Unless the file specified by `file_name` is in the same folder as your program, `os.startfile(file_name)` is not going to know where the file is. You should use the full path when using `os.startfile()`: `os.startfile(path)`. Unless there is a reason you need to start the basename all by itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the filename from the path as follows:

```
path = "C:users/desktop/book.txt"

filename = path.split("/")[-1]

print(filename)
```